# Efficiently process through 3 millions Pandas dataframe rows

Tags: python, csv, pandas, optimization, dataframe

I neeed to process a large csv file with 3 million rows, and 7 columns. 
 Shape of DataFrame: (3421083, 7)

My plan is to delete all rows that contain a certain value (customer id) Here is how I proceed:

```
#keep track of iterations
track = 0

#import all transactions (orders.csv)
transactions = pd.read_csv('transactions.csv')

#We select all orders that are electronics orders and put them into a df
is_electronics = transactions[transactions.type == "electronics"]          

#Create arrays that will store users to destroy in transactions.csv 
users_to_remove = []

#iterate to add appropriate values:

#  we add all users that ordered electronics  to a list 
for user in is_electronics.user_id:
    users_to_remove.append(user)


#We delete from orders.csv
for user in users_to_remove:
    transactions = transactions[transactions.user_id != user]
    track += 1
    if track == 100000:
        print(track)
        track = 0

transactions.to_csv('not_electronics.csv', index = False)
```

This operation takes ages im running it since 1 hour and it still didnt finish.

I have a quad core desktop i5 with 3.2 ghz and 8gb of ram. But in the activity monitor, the computer only uses 5 gbs of ram and 40% of my cpu.

Is there any way to speed up the computation of this process? Either by changing the code or using other libraries?

I also have a gpu (gtx 970) can I use it to process this?

Thank you.

Comment: You have over 3 million entries, and your code is [accidentally quadratic](http://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/). Bad combo.

Comment: I am not even sure why you'd want to use pandas for this. Just stream the csv instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `isin`

```
is_electronics = transactions.type == 'electronics'
users_to_remove = transactions.loc[is_electronics, 'user_id'].unique()
transactions[~transactions.user_id.isin(users_to_remove)]
```

---

**Deleted Prior Suggestion that was here to be safe**

---

For posterity, this is @DSM's suggestion

```
is_electronics = transactions.type.values == 'electronics'
users = transactions.user_id.values
transactions[~np.in1d(users, users[is_electronics])]
```

Comment: Unless you specify `assume_unique` to np.in1d, I think it does its own unique-ing anyhow.  So might as well just pass the users directly, IMHO.

Comment: @DSM Thanks, I definitely want to `assume_unique=True` as I'm taking advantage of the fact that `pd.unique` doesn't sort.  I haven't tested to see if that makes difference.  But thats the thought process.

Comment: I'm not sure that will work.  assume_unique means that we're assuming _both_ are unique, I think.  I'd just drop the pd.unique and let np.in1d do the work itself.

Comment: @DSM I just tested it... the first does not have to be unique.

Comment: The documentation for [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) states `assume_unique=True` means *both* input arrays are unique.  Also, note that `isin` will use `np.in1d` under the hood if the input data is [large enough](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.2/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L405-L406).

Comment: note that isin will use np.in1d for very large inputs  (its an empirical perf optimization)